# How to add a submit button to dropzone

Tags: drag-and-drop, dropzone.js

Hello everyone i am using dropzone.js to upload pictures to the server with php, but i kind of having problem with it.

I was wondering if there is anyway to disable the dropzone.js auto upload to the server on drag and drop image or on click and select image and use a clickable submit button to manually submit the image to the server

Please any advice or help perhaps a simple code will be appreciated.

**Edited**

I still haven't got an answer to my questions.

Seriously i feel like this people building this stuff doesn't got it right because the stuff is useless in someways, are they trying to tell me that when a user uploads its profile picture and the dropzone will be stuck there looking at them and them looking at it without a submit button or a confirmation message that the picture has been uploaded then they should continue? seriously?

Comment: Why not use separate dropzones for each file and set `autoProcessQueue : false` to stop auto upload to server?

Comment: then do what after the file has been dragged and dropped? as i can set it to false but i want to show a submit button that when the file has been dragged and dropped into dropzone the user can click on that button and then the file will then submit to the server and redirect user to another a successful page or a homepage

Answer (score 2):

You can define button in your HTML Form such as

```html
<button id="submit-all">Submit all files</button>
```

and then add this script

```js
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.gif,.bmp,.jpeg",
  maxFilesize: 1,
  parallelUploads: 10,
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  init: function() {
    var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
    myDropzone = this; // closure

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      myDropzone.processQueue(); 
      // autoProcessQueue: true// Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
    });

    // You might want to show the submit button only when 
    // files are dropped here:
    this.on("addedfile", function() {
      // Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.
    });
  }
};
```

Hope this solves the problem.

Reference: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Upload-all-files-with-a-button

Comment: respect to parallelUploads: 10 because when u use  myDropzone.processQueue(); just submit 2 files only due to the default value of parell uploaded files is 2 and you can set it up to u